# Set image width dynamically in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, interface-builder

I am trying to set the width of an image dynamically using MonoTouch. I have added the image to the view using Xcode Interface Builder.

What I want to do is keep the X and Y values of the image exactly the same. I just want the width of the image to change depending on a float value.

Example: If I placed the the image on the view at X = 50 and Y = 50 and the image size is W = 100 and H = 100 then I want to change the width dynamically based on conditions. I have tried to set the images' width dynamically like this:

```
img.Bounds.Width = 150;
```

and like this

```
img.Bounds.Size.Width = 150;
```

I have also tried to create a new RectangleF and setting the bounds equal to that Rectangle like this

```
RectangleF fillrect = new RectangleF(50, 50,
150, img.Bounds.Height);
```

and then setting the image bounds to that rectangle like this:

```
img.Bounds = fillrect;
```

The above method sizes the image but then moves the image to the incorrect place (X and Y values).

I have also tried various methods using SizeF but to no avail.

How can I just set the width of the image and keep it in the same place I placed it on interface builder?

And also how to change the X and Y values so that I can move another image based on the growth of the aforementioned image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like changing of Bounds applies around the Center of the view.

Try to set new Frame instead:

```
img.Frame = fillrect;
```

Location will be the same, but Size will be changed.